# Is there a way to see the Markdown source a Stack Overflow question?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I see a few questions that use Markdown to nicely format the question.

Is there a way to see the Markdown source for a Stack Overflow question?

Comment: Edit worked well, thanks. There should be a SO duplicate detection service since I was not able to find the answer before I ask here.  I am sure there are some other search keywords that can find the answer